# Rebase after force push

Tags: git, branch, rebase

I have a feature branch A. Then I start developing a second feature dependent on A, so I base my new feature branch B on A:

```
git checkout A
git checkout -B B
```

I do some work on B, so now on B I have commit 1 (from A) and the new commit 2.
Our company always squashes all commits of one PR as much together as possible, so at one point I'm force-pushing A so that A has only commit 1'. Now I want to rebase B to A (or master, after A is merged), but since I force-pushed A, git tries to apply commit 1, which obviously fails.

2 methods to solve this, which both are not great:

using git cherry-pick:

```
git checkout B
git checkout -B B2
git log // copy latest commit id
git checkout B
git reset --hard A
git cherry-pick <commit-id>
```

using soft reset:

```
git checkout B
git reset --soft HEAD~1
git stash
git reset --hard A
git stash pop
git commit -a -m "msg"
```

Is there a "git method" for sorting this out? I know that it's maybe not best practice to always squash the commits, but that I can't change. Or is there maybe a better way to base one branch on another?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Ultimately, you'll want `git rebase --onto`.  Sometimes you won't need to do anything special, though.

#### The setup

Let's draw your initial situation:

```
...--A--B   <-- master
         \
          C   <-- feature/A
           \
            D   <-- feature/B
```

That is, there's some series of commits on some main line (I've called it `master` here but it might be `develop` or whatever), then one commit on your `feature/A`, then one commit on your `feature/B`.  The parent of commit `D`, on your `feature/B`, is your commit `C`, on both `feature/B` and `feature/A`.

Somewhat later, you've added a second commit to your `feature/A`, giving:

```
...--A--B   <-- master
         \
          C--E   <-- feature/A
           \
            D   <-- feature/B
```

Eventually, `feature/A` is to be merged to `master`, and per some policy rule, you've made a new commit `F` that is the combination of `C` and `E` so that you now have:

```
          F   <-- feature/A
         /
...--A--B   <-- master
         \
          C--E   [abandoned]
           \
            D   <-- feature/B
```

At this point you'd like to copy `D` to some new commit `D'` that looks exactly like `D` in terms of its diff against its parent, but where `D'`'s parent is `F` instead of `C`.

Git offers an easy-ish way to get what you want:

```
git checkout feature/B
git rebase --onto feature/A something-goes-here
```

The problem is the `something-goes-here` part.  What goes there?

#### Copying some commit(s)

The `git rebase` command is, essentially, just a series of `git cherry-pick` commands followed by a branch label motion.  As you've already discovered, `git cherry-pick` does what you want: it copies a commit.  In fact, it can copy more than one commit (using what Git calls, internally, the *sequencer*).

That is, it compares each commit to be copied to the commit's *parent*, to see what changed.  Then, it makes those same changes to the *current* commit, and if all goes well, commits the result.

For instance, let's start with this situation.  I've stuck in a new label, `saved-A`, for the moment, to remember commit `E`, and I've added the name `new-B` and added `HEAD` in parentheses to show that *current branch* is `new-B` and the *current commit* is commit `F`:

```
          F   <-- feature/A, new-B (HEAD)
         /
...--A--B   <-- master
         \
          C--E   <-- saved-A
           \
            D   <-- feature/B
```

We can now run `git cherry-pick feature/B`.  We're telling Git: *Compare commit `D` to its parent `C`, then make the same changes to where we are now, at commit `F`, and commit the result.*  If all goes well, we get:

```
            D'   <-- new-B (HEAD)
           /
          F   <-- feature/A
         /
...--A--B   <-- master
         \
          C--E   <-- saved-A
           \
            D   <-- feature/B
```

All we need to do now is yank the name `feature/B` over to point to commit `D'`, and then drop the name `new-B`:

```
            D'   <-- feature/B (HEAD)
           /
          F   <-- feature/A
         /
...--A--B   <-- master
         \
          C--E   <-- saved-A
           \
            D   [abandoned]
```

Again, the first part of this is just what `git cherry-pick` does: copy one commit.  The *last* part of this is something that `git rebase` does: move a branch label like `feature/B`.

The key here is that `git rebase` copies *some* commits.  **Which ones?**  The *default* answer is wrong answer for you!

#### What `git rebase` does, in a nutshell

Let's look at a slightly different drawing:

```
...--A--B   <-- target
      \
       C--D--E   <-- current (HEAD)
```

Here, we are "on" branch `current`, i.e., `git status` will say `on branch current`.  The tip commit of `current` is commit `E`: `E`'s hash ID is the hash ID stored in the name `refs/heads/current`.

If we now run:

```
git rebase target
```

Git will *copy* commits `C-D-E` to new commits `C'-D'-E'` and place the new commits atop `target` and then move the branch name, like this:

```
          C'-D'-E'   <-- current (HEAD)
         /
...--A--B   <-- target
      \
       C--D--E   [abandoned]
```

That's usually what we want.  But: **How did `git rebase` know to copy `C-D-E` but not to copy `A` too?**

The answer is that `git rebase` uses Git's internal "list some commits" operation, `git rev-list`, with a *stop point*.  The rebase documentation claims that what `git rebase` does is run:

```
git rev-list target..HEAD
```

which is a bit of a white lie: it's close enough, and illustrative.  The exact details are trickier and we'll get there in a bit.  For now, let's look at the `target..` part of `target..HEAD`.  This tells Git: *don't list any commits that you can find by starting at the target and working backwards.*

Since `target` names commit `B`, that means: *don't copy commit `B`*.  Well, we already weren't going to copy commit `B`, so no big deal.  But it *also* means: *don't copy commit `A`*.  Why not?  Because commit `B` points back to commit `A`.  Commit `A` is on both branches, `target` and `current`.  So we *would* have copied `A`, but we don't, because it's on the *do not copy* list.  There are commits *before* `A` too, but they are all on the *do not copy* part, so none of them get copied.

Hence it's commits `C-D-E` that get copied here: they are on the to-copy list, and not stopped-out by being on the do-not-copy list.

So, what `git rebase` does, in a nutshell, is this:

1. Remember which branch `HEAD` is attached to.
2. List out some commit hash IDs to copy.
3. Detach `HEAD` from the current branch.
4. Copy the listed commits, one at a time, as if by `git cherry-pick`.
5. *Move* the branch name that `HEAD` was attached to, to where we are now.
6. Re-attach `HEAD` to the moved branch.

Note that things can go wrong during step 4.  In particular, copying a commit, as if by `git cherry-pick`—whether or not this actually uses `git cherry-pick`—can have a *merge conflict*.  If so, the rebase stops in the middle, with a detached HEAD.  That's why knowing about step 3 is important.  But we'll leave that for other question-and-answers (along with the details about whether rebase actually does use cherry-pick itself: sometimes it does, sometimes it fakes it).

#### The truth about which commits get copied

We mentioned that the `target..HEAD` thing above was a white lie: a simplification, meant to make it easier to comprehend which commits get copied.  It's time for the truth now.

- First, `git rebase` normally *omits* merge commits entirely.  Any commit that would be generated by the `git rev-list` above is knocked out if it's a merge (has two or more parents).  As long as you have no merge commits in your list, this doesn't matter anyway.
- Second, `git rebase` *also* omits commits that are *patch-ID equivalent* to some other commits.  This uses the `git patch-id` program.  We won't go into details here, other than to observe that to get the "some other commits" part, Git actually has to use `git rev-list target...HEAD`, with three dots.  This produces a *symmetric difference* list, of commits reachable from `HEAD` but not target, and also commits reachable from `target` but not `HEAD`.  For (much) more about reachability, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).  The rebase command then uses `git patch-id` on each commit in the two lists—which it's generated internally so it knows which commit hash goes with which list—and knocks out those that have matching patch IDs.  The effect of this is that if commit `B`, for instance, is *already* the same (cherry-pick-wise) as commit `D`, instead of copying `C-D-E`, we'll just copy `C-E`, to get:

  ```
            C'-E'   <-- current (HEAD)
           /
  ...--A--B   <-- target
        \
         C--D--E   [abandoned]
  ```

  because commits `B` and `D` "do the same thing".
- Last, and most important to us here, `--onto` lets us use a different *target*.

In the example above, we ran:

```
git rebase target
```

and `target` was both our *stop argument* for `git rev-list stop..HEAD` *and* our target, for where Git put the copies.  But we can run:

```
git rebase --onto target stop
```

and now `git rebase` will use our *stop* argument for the `stop` part of the `git rev-list`, while continuing to use our *target* argument for the place the copies go.

So, suppose we're given *this* now:

```
...--A--B   <-- target
      \
       C   <-- another
        \
         D--E   <-- current (HEAD)
```

and we run:

```
git rebase --onto target another
```

We've now told Git that the *stop* argument for our rebase is `another`, which selects commit `C`.  Our rebase will use `git rev-list` on `another..HEAD`, or `C..E`, which means that the list of commits to copy will consist of just `D-E`.

That list will get further filtered by the patch-id and no-merges rules, but as long as `B` *isn't* the same as `D`, we'll end up with:

```
          D'-E'  <-- current (HEAD)
         /
...--A--B   <-- target
      \
       C   <-- another
        \
         D--E   [abandoned]
```

That is, we'll copy *only* the two commits `D-E` that are reachable from `current`, omitting commit `C` that is reachable from `another`.

#### Putting it all together

Here's your setup at the time you want to do the commit copying:

```
          F   <-- feature/A
         /
...--A--B   <-- master
         \
          C--E   <-- saved-A
           \
            D   <-- feature/B (HEAD)
```

Note that we've added the name `saved-A` to remember what *not* to copy.  We don't want to copy commits `C` and `E`.  We wouldn't copy `E` anyway, but this is an easy way to remember *everything* not to copy.

We currently have `feature/B` checked out (commit `D`).  We don't need to create a name, `new-B`, so we did not do that.  Now we just run:

```
git rebase --onto feature/A saved-A
```

Git will now list out the commits to copy: every commit that's on the current branch, `feature/B`, *except for* every commit that's on `saved-A`.  So that's commit `D`.

Git now detaches HEAD, moves to commit `F`—our `--onto` target—and copies `D` to produce `D'`.  That finishes the list of commits to copy, so having successfully copied `D` to `D'`, Git forcibly moves the name `feature/B` to point to `D'` and re-attaches `HEAD`, giving us:

```
            D'  <-- feature/B (HEAD)
           /
          F   <-- feature/A
         /
...--A--B   <-- master
         \
          C--E   <-- saved-A
           \
            D   [abandoned]
```

which is just what we want.

We can now delete the name `saved-A`.

#### What if you didn't save the name?

What if you've rebased `feature/A` already but forgot to save the commit hash ID of commit `E` somewhere?

Fortunately, you don't *have* to have saved the hash ID of either `E` or `C`.  You can:

- find them using `git log`, or
- use `git reflog` to find the hash IDs that `feature/A` used to name, or
- do anything else you like to find them.

Raw hash IDs work, so you can just run:

```
git rebase --onto feature/A <hash-ID-of-E-or-C>
```

after you find the hash ID.  (Use cut-and-paste or similar to get the hash ID right; typing it, or even a unique prefix of it, in by hand is a recipe for errors.)

Reflog names also work, so pretty often you can do:

```
git rebase --onto feature/A feature/A@{1}
```

where `feature/A@{1}` is the reflog name you'd see for the hash ID of commit `E`, when you run `git reflog feature/A` to list out the previous hash IDs for `feature/A`.  (`feature/A@{2}` probably names commit `C`, so that would also work.)

The key is to find the commit(s) you want to omit, and use those with `git rebase --onto`.  Set the *target* based on where the copies should go, and set the stop-point—the thing that [the `git rebase` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) calls the *upstream* argument—to a hash ID that stops out the commits you *don't* want copied.

#### When don't you need anything special?

If your squashed commits have the same patch ID as the original commits, `git rebase`'s *leave out commits that have matching patch IDs* will do all the work for you.  This will generally only happen if you only had *one* commit that got squash-merged to some other branch.

The `--onto` trick always works, so you don't really need to worry about this case, but if it happens a lot, it's nice to know.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed answer! That's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: You made my day !!! git rebase --onto branch-you-wanna-rebase-from commit-id-from-where-in-your-current-branch-you-wanna-start

Comment: Do you think we can make this from remote also ? like git rebase --onto origin/branch-fucked-up-by-push-force COMMITID-in-local

Comment: @ThomasAumaitre: The `--onto` target, if provided, functions only to locate a raw commit hash ID. Anything that `git rev-parse` can turn into a raw hash ID is fine. Try running `git rev-parse master`, `git rev-parse origin/foo`, and so on to see how this works. The other argument, the one `git rebase` calls `upstream`, is used the same way. (If you provide a *third* argument, as in `git rebase --onto target upstream branch`, that third argument *isn't* handled like this! I always recommend not using a third argument here to avoid confusion.)

Comment: @torek Men you saved me, I am so prepared for Monday morning big day for me we go in production ! I just wanna know if I can do something like this git rebase --onto origin/develop 6f80f76c68e4b0b657400e938016bcc972520e34 but yes we should why not ?

Comment: Yes, that's sensible as long as `6f80f76c68e4b0b657400e938016bcc972520e34` is the hash ID of some commit that finds the commits you'd like excluded.

Comment: I mean origin/develop should work, isn't it :) ?

Comment: `origin/develop` is fine too, as long as it exists and names a commit. :-) It's a lot easier for *humans* to tell whether a sensible name exists, though, than to tell whether some big ugly hash ID is the right one...

Comment: Lol it's not a branch name, you know when you do git remote -v you get origin the remote name always

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "name", not "branch name". Remote-tracking names are still names, and still make sense to humans. We are odd creatures: why does a name like `origin/develop` seem to have meaning, when a hash ID like `6f80f76c68e4b0b657400e938016bcc972520e34` doesn't? :-)

Comment: You rock for real

Comment: Amazing! I was tearing my hair out today with the following situation: 

1. start feature branch A, add some commits
2. start new feature branch B, based on A, and add some commits
3. clean up A with interactive rebasing (edit individual commits)
4. try to rebase B onto A: *booom*

With your help I could solve it like this:

`rebase --onto A <the one commit before the new commits>`